# Intention: annotated class automatically extends superclass

Tags: java, annotations

I have a Annotation

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public @interface Car {
}
```

and a abstract superclass

```
public abstract class AbstractCar {
    ...
}
```

which works perfectly well on this class:

```
@Car
public class MyBlueCar extends AbstractCar {
    ...
}
```

However, I did not find a way to omit the "extends AbstractCar" in the implementation. As all implementations of Car must extend AbstractCar, I'm looking for a solution to include the "extends AbstractCar" in the custom annotation. So that a class that is annotated with @Car is also a AbstractCar, without explicitely mentioning it in the code with the "extends" part.

Until now, I have not succeeded; extending the @interface does not seem logical and does not work.

My question: Is this possible at all and, if yes, how can I do it?

Thanks for any suggestions and input.

Patrick

Comment: you cannot omit `extends`

Comment: I feared that this would be the answer. Can you explain why 'extends' can not be handled by the annotation?

Comment: It's just the language design. I have to ask you why it should be handled by the annotation? Where did you get this idea?

Comment: I just thought about redundancy. Why should I need to write to code parts (`@Car` and `extends AbstractCar`) when there might be a possibility to do it in one piece.

Comment: Correction: Why should I need to write *two* code parts...

Comment: Anyway, thanks for your clarification, Lino.

Comment: This is not redundant believe me, because it is needed and can't be taken away (`MyBlueCar` must be a Car)

Comment: You could annotate Car with Inherited and omit @Car from MyBlueCar instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After quite some further research and discussions, I want to add the outcome to make things more obvious.

Technically it's not possible, as already commented in the question.
Reason: The annotation is used at runtime, while the "extends" part is used at compiletime. These two things can't mix.

The intention is an unfortunate choice. When I have behaviour that all Cars should share, I can't provide this with Annotations. So I need the "extends" part in the code.

Thanks to all who helped me understand.
Patrick